# how to get data or query from Many to Many?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have product and code entities, and I make ManyToMany relationship for them, so it gonna be Product_Code

so the Product_Code will have product_id and product_id

I really want to fetch data from the product by the code, but the result I want it I want detail from product values and code values also, I don't know how to do that on JPA

I was thinking to get the product code first, then find the id product on Product_Code table for that id , and then get data from it and find the id of code again on code entity, 
i am sure there is way to fetch data for this, but i don't know how, and i do like to get simple way to understand how it works

i am very new here

my entity product something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
@Setter
@Getter
@DynamicUpdate
public class Product extends Base {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Code> codes;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String Name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    public int hasCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

}
```

and here is my Code entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CODE")
@DynamicUpdate
@Setter
@Getter
public class Voucher extends Base {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "PRODUCT_CODE",
               joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID"))
    private Set<Product> products;

    @Column(name = "CODE", unique = true)
    private String codeName;

    @Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false)
    private String type;

    private String descriptions;

    public int hasCode() {
            return Objects.hashCode(getId());
        }
}
```

i really want to get the all of data when i try to find by code 
let say that i want to find a product with code like "A7", so i want to get from product entity and then i will get the detail code entity also with the product_id and code_id like that product

when i tried to `Product findByCode(String code)` or `Product findOneByCode(String code)`
the result is the `Base` entity which i extends not the Product entity , 
the `Base` entity is reusable entity like generate `id, token, createdAt, deletedAt, updatedAt`

Comment: You want to get List<Product> according to specific Voucher.codeName?

Comment: yess, is that possible?

Comment: i was tried this "SELECT p.name , v.code "
                + " from Product p " +
                " INNER JOIN ProductCode cp ON p.id = cp.productId " +
                " INNER JOIN Code v on v.id = cp.codeId WHERE v.code = ?1" but failed

Comment: Yes sure, I recommend you to use `JpaSpecificationExecutor` repository and `CriteriaBuilder.isMember` function. Select the `Code` by id and pass it to isMember function.

Comment: do u have example, please?? I don't find by id, I want find by the name of code

Comment: Then you have to select your `Voucher` by name using `VoucherRepository` and then pass the entity object to `isMember` of your specification.

Comment: let say in repo =>  Voucher findByCode(String code), and then how to define isMember??

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `Specification<Product>` on  `JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product>`-enabled repository.

1. Make sure your `ProductRepository` implements `JpaSpecifiactionExecutor<Product>`

then, somewhere in your `@Service` with both `VoucherRepository` and `ProductRepository` injected do:

```
//implement a method in VoucherRepository findByName which returns Voucher instance.
Voucher code = voucherRepository.findByName("A7");

//then pass the instance to isMember function in ProductRepository
List<Product> products = productRepository.findAll((r, q, b) -> b.isMember(code, Product_.codes));
```

**Comments**

`r, q, b` are method parameters for lambda-expression like implementation of `Specification<Product>` overriding method `toPredicate`. If your project restricts you using Java version 7 and below, you could implement this object using the following:

```
Specification<Product> spec = new Specification<Product>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Product> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            return criteriaBuilder.isMember(code, root.get(Product_.codes));
        }
};
```

**Parameters**

`r` stands for root element `Root<Product>`

`q` stands for criteria query `CriteriaQuery<?>`

`b` stands for criteria builder `CriteriaBuilder`

`Product_.*` is a static metamodel for your `Product` entity. It could be either generated autmatically using JPA model generator or created manually using `@Staticmetamodel` annotation.

By executing `findAll(Specification<Product>)` you're making filtering-like select where your result List will contain only the products matching your criteria.

Edit:

Your `Product` metamodel could look like (for now), but however, I recommend using metamodel generator.

```
@StaticMetamodel(Product.class)
public class Product_ {
      public static volatile SetAttribute<Product, Code> codes;
}
```

Comment: what is `r, q, b `? and should i have Paramater on product repo for findAll ??

Comment: i still confused

Comment: i still dont understand about this, how to create  @Staticmetamodel correct way?

Comment: Added simple example. Please, Google it as this is not a problem related to the question you're asking.

Comment: @StaticMetamodel is write on repo ? or service ?

Comment: No, you have to put it on your metamodel class, which has the same name like your entity but has a "_" at the end of the name and shares the same package. Example in answer.